# Get the path of song playing in VLC using python script

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, scripting, file-descriptors, vlc

I am trying to  get the path of song playing in VLC using python script. I have already find out the Process ID of vlc using

```
pgrep -x vlc
```

And I can also display the all file descriptors of vlc using

```
readlink /proc/PID/fd/*
```

I get many file descriptors after executiong above statement.
I don't know how to get the path of song playing?